# Showing the existence of an eigenvector using groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $\text{GL}_2(\mathbb{F}_p)$ act on $\mathbb{F}_p^2$ ($2$-vectors with entries in $\mathbb{F}_p$) by matrix multiplication:

$$\mathbf{M}\in\text{GL}_2(\mathbb{F}_p),\;\mathbf{v}\in\mathbb{F}_p^2:\quad \mathbf{M}(\mathbf{v})=\mathbf{Mv}$$ 
I would like to prove the following claim:

> If $\mathbf{A}\in\text{GL}_2(\mathbb{F}_p)$ has $\text{ord}\,\mathbf{A}=p$ then there exists non-zero $\mathbf{w}\in\mathbb{F}_p^2$ such that $\mathbf{A}(\mathbf{w})=\mathbf{w}$

The hint given is to use the orbit-stabiliser theorem. I think the idea is to show that for some $\mathbf{w},\;p$ cannot divide $|\text{orb}(\mathbf{w})|$ which in turns means $\mathbf{A}\in\text{stab}(\mathbf{w})$ which gives us what we want. But I cannot seem to make the initial argument. Help?

Comment: What is $\text{ord} \mathbf A$?

Comment: @RobertLewis Order of $\mathbf{A}$: the least positive integer $n$ such that $\mathbf{A}^n=\text{identity}$

Comment: I suspected as much; thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $G$ be the subgroup generated by $A$. Then, $G$ acts on $\mathbb{F}_{p}^{2}$. Note that the size of the orbit of each element must divide the order of $G$, which is $p$. Hence, the orbit of each element must be $p$ or $1$.

But note that $(0, 0) \in \mathbb{F}_{p}^{2}$ has a singleton orbit. Hence, we must have another orbit of size 1 because otherwise, the sum of the sizes of the orbits could not be $p^{2}$, the size of $\mathbb{F}_{p}^{2}$ (as $p$ would then divide the size of $\mathbb{F}_{p}^{2}$ but not the sum of the size of the orbits.

Hence, we must have a $w \in \mathbb{F}_{p}^{2}$ such that $G \cdot w = \{w\}$ as desired.