# Non-obvious deduction regarding conjugates in $\text{GL}_2(\mathbb{F}_p)$

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, finite-fields

Let $\text{GL}_2(\mathbb{F}_p)$ act on $\mathbb{F}_p^2,$ the set of $2$-vectors with entries in $\mathbb{F}_p$, by matrix multiplication.

$[\,$Prove that$\,]$ for any $\mathbf{A}\in\text{GL}_2(\mathbb{F}_p)$ with $\text{ord}\,\mathbf{A}=p$, there exists $\mathbf{v}\in\mathbb{F}_p^2\setminus \{\mathbf{0}\}$ such that: $$\mathbf{A}(\mathbf{v})=\mathbf{v}\quad [\,\text{done}\,]$$

Deduce that $\mathbf{A}$ is conjugate in $\text{GL}_2(\mathbb{F}_p)$ to $\begin{pmatrix} 1\quad1\\0\quad1\end{pmatrix}$

$\big[$taken from $2012\;7\text{E}$ of part $\mathsf{IA}$ of the Cambridge tripos$\,]$

---

I am having a hard time seeing how one would *deduce* the claim from the previous statement. I can prove that $\mathbf{A}$ is conjugate to said matrix using results from linear algebra, but I think this is missing the point of the question. Would anyone care to offer insight on this? Thank you for any suggestions/help.

**Note:** just to stress the question: the problem is in the context of a purely group-theoretic exam; I am after a solution which uses no linear algebra at all.

Comment: All better :-) Yeah, I would use linear algebra to get it to upper unitriangular, [1,t;0,1]. Then you can use diagonals to scale it to [1,1;0,1].

Comment: Well, you know that $1$ is an eigenvalue and you know that $A$ satisfies $x^p - 1 = (x - 1)^p$.  Can you prove its Jordan canonical form is as above?

Comment: @JackSchmidt Thanks. And yes, this was my first thought as well. The issue that this is taken from purely group-theoretic exam paper, so I would expect there to be a solution which involves no linear algebra at all.

Comment: At least in these parts linear algebra is taught before groups and finite fields.

Comment: You can do the first part using Orbit-stabilizer (similar to "class equation"), and then repeat it on the quotient space $\mathbb{F}_p^2 / \langle \mathbf{v} \rangle$, so get $A(\mathbf{w}) = \mathbf{w} + t \mathbf{v}$. Module theory is very common in finite groups. The diagonal thing at the end seems like you have to just throw it in, since it is false in SL and larger GL.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/791055/showing-the-existence-of-an-eigenvector-using-groups is that part of the question. Same notation.

Answer (score 2):

This is equivalent to showing that there's a basis with respect to which the matrix of $A$ is $\begin{bmatrix} 1&1 \\ 0&1\end{bmatrix}$. If you choose the first basis vector to be $v$, then the first column of the matrix will be $\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}$.

Now, the other diagonal entry will have to be $1$, since taking powers of an upper triangular matrix just raises the diagonal entries to that power, and $1$ is the only residue that satisfies $a^p=1$. Now you have that the matrix is conjugate to $\begin{bmatrix} 1&a \\ 0&1\end{bmatrix}$. Now you just have to conjugate this to make $a=1$.

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that...I had it right the first time.